# CSS media query looks good locally but not when hosted online

Tags: css, media-queries

Locally my `banner-home2.png` looks as I need it.

However, when uploaded it's size gets bigger. (I'm hosting this on heroku, but the css file is on Amazon).

And I can see that in these [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EzOONJ), it also look wrong (bigger than it should be):

Online version:

[stickersgallito.pe](http://stickersgallito.pe):

[image]

Local version (correct size):

[image]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EzOONJ

These are my media queries on Amazon:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/home.css">
```

`home.css` (media queries):

```
.my_header_bg_color {

    /*background-color: #4FB99F;*/
    /*background-color: #00ADB5;*/
    /*background-color: #6BB983;*/
    background-color: #00AD80;
}


/* standard media queries breakpoints */

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
    /* smartphones, iPhone, portrait 480x320 phones */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 8%;
        z-index: -600;
    }

    .productos_finales_home img {

        padding-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .my_home_banner_image {
        bottom: 0;
        top: 0;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 60%;
        display: block;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: 165px;
    }

    /*.my_home_banner_image {*/
    /*display: none;*/
    /*}*/
    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 36px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }



    .btn-comentario {
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: #969696;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #fff;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
        letter-spacing: 0;
        line-height: 1.2;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        -ms-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        -o-box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, .09) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .09) 100%);
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        padding: 22px 30px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: none;
    }

.my_home_banner_left {
    margin-left: 10px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.stickers_referenciales {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

}

@media (min-width: 481px) {
    /* portrait e-readers (Nook/Kindle), smaller tablets @ 600 or @ 640 wide. */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 8%;
        z-index: -600;
    }


    .my_home_banner_image {

        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: -0px;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 40%;
        display: block;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: 185px;
    }


    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .btn-comentario {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .my_home_banner_left {
        margin-left: 20px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 641px) {
    /* portrait tablets, portrait iPad, landscape e-readers, landscape 800x480 or 854x480 phones */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 8%;
        z-index: -600;
    }


    .my_home_banner_image {

        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: -0px;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 70%;
    }


    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .btn-comentario {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .my_home_banner_left {
        margin-left: 20px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .my_home_banner_lef_text {
        margin-left: 10px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 961px) {
    /* tablet, landscape iPad, lo-res laptops ands desktops */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 8%;
        z-index: -600;
    }


    .my_home_banner_image {

        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: -0px;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 60%;
    }


    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .btn-comentario {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .my_home_banner_left {
        margin-left: 20px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
    /* big landscape tablets, laptops, and desktops */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 8%;
        z-index: -600;
    }


    .my_home_banner_image {

        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: -0px;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 55%;
    }


    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .btn-comentario {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .my_home_banner_left {
        margin-left: 20px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .subscribe_field {
        width: 350px;
    }

}

@media (min-width: 1281px) {
    /* hi-res laptops and desktops */
    .my_home_banner {
        bottom: 0;
        margin-right: 8%;
        z-index: -600;
    }


    .my_home_banner_image {

        bottom: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: -0px;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        width: 70%;
    }

    /*.my_home_banner_image_left {*/
    /*display: none;*/
    /*}*/
    .my_home_banner_title {
        color: white;
        font-size: 50px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .my_home_banner_subtitle {
        margin-top: 0%;
        padding-top: 0%;
    }

    .btn, h2, p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .btn-comentario {
        margin-bottom: 100px;
    }

    .my_home_banner_left {
        margin-left: 20px;
        z-index: 100;
    }

    .subscribe_field {
        width: 350px;
    }
}


.center-video {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Are you manually deploying the new css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Inside **home.css** Line no 296

```
@media (min-width: 1281px)
.my_home_banner_image {
bottom: 0;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
z-index: 0;
width: 40%;
}
```

Maybe it occurs because of server-side HTML, CSS or any other language version is different than in localhost we have. But you can set that thing as I gave above for more than 1281 screen size.

Answer (score 1):

just modify this `.my_home_banner_image` class add `top` and reduce the `width` in your website it will works

```
@media (min-width: 1281px)
.my_home_banner_image {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: -0px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 55%;
    top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Close, but no need to add `top:25px`; it moved the image outside the banner.

Comment: Yes you have to add top 0 or some value and reduce your width